# Loading Spark-SQL with different data sources

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am currently exploring on using Spark SQL (1.4.1). I have 3 different Data sources (RDBMS) to load the data from anyone of them at one point of time. Each of the RDBMS source has different table structure.

In order to have common infrastructure in Spark SQL, should I export the RDBMS Data source to a common table structure of .CSV file and then load using Spark SQL ?

Comment: Why would you export to csv? Just load each source using JDBC reader.

Comment: Thank you. On the same line i have another question. In order to load large data from RDBMS should i use RDBMS-> SQOOP -> HDFS and then read from SPARK OR can i use SPARK SQL to directly load the data from RDBMS ? Please suggest which is more efficient and optimized way. Thank you.

Comment: Please ask it as a separate question.